# Can't see "Create deploy package as a zip file" option in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Can't see this option in Package/Publish Web page. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015.

[image]

Picture from [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/building-and-packaging-web-application-projects):
[image]

edit: As a workaround, I can build a publish package as instructed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). But still don't know why my version can't see that option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope you have already found a solution to this problem.

As from Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 they removed those settings from the Package/Publish Web project settings. You will have to access this package option from the Publish dialogue.

Right-Click on your project and select **Publish**, Create a new Profile.
In the **Connection** tab, Select **Web Deploy Package** for the **Publish Method** option.

Hope this helps